# Does Spark support multiple users?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a 3-node spark 2.3.1 cluster running at the moment, and I'm also running a zeppelin server using a normal user, like ulab.

From zeppelin, I ran the commands:

```
%spark
val file = sc.textFile("file:///mnt/glusterfs/test/testfile")
file.saveAsTextFile("/mnt/glusterfs/test/testfile2")
```

It report a lot of error messages, something like:

```
WARN [2018-09-14 05:44:50,540] ({pool-2-thread-8} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2302) - Job 20180907-130718_39068508 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: null, result: %text file: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///mnt/glusterfs/test/testfile MapPartitionsRDD[49] at textFile at <console>:51
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  ...
  ... 64 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{path=file:/mnt/glusterfs/test/testfile2/_temporary/0/task_20180914054253_0050_m_000018/part-00018; isDirectory=false; length=33554979; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1536903780000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to file:/mnt/glusterfs/test/testfile2/part-00018
```

And I found that some temporary files owned by user root, while some owned by ulab, like the following:

```
bash-4.4# ls -l testfile2
total 32773
drwxr-xr-x    3 ulab     ulab          4096 Sep 14 05:42 _temporary
-rw-r--r--    1 ulab     ulab      33554979 Sep 14 05:44 part-00018
bash-4.4# ls -l testfile2/_temporary/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  210 ulab     ulab          4096 Sep 14 05:44 0
bash-4.4# ls -l testfile2/_temporary/0
total 832
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 14 05:42 task_20180914054253_0050_m_000000
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 14 05:42 task_20180914054253_0050_m_000001
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 14 05:42 task_20180914054253_0050_m_000002
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 14 05:42 task_20180914054253_0050_m_000003
....
```

Is there any setup to let all these temporary files created by ulab? so we can use multiple users in spark driver to isolate the priviledges.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable 'User Impersonate' option for spark interpreter which will start the spark job as logged-in user.
Refer this [link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/manual/userimpersonation.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you, Saravanan. I have tried 'user impersonate', but it works when I write to alluxio through spark, and doesn't work when I write to a network filesystem, like glusterfs, it just writes these files as root. Also I think when I run zeppelin using a normal user, it's the same thing as impersonate to that user.